# When I apply a lambda function to every row of a dataframe, the dataframe it returns has a list object in each row instead of a dataframe row, how fix

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

When I apply a lambda function to every row of a dataframe, the dataframe it returns has a list object in each row instead of a dataframe row. Ideally each element in the list would be its own column in a dataframe row, but really all I need is to count how many times the first element of the list is 'True'. I can't figure out how to get the first element of each list which are in the first column in a dataframe.

```
numbertrue = evaluation.iloc[:, 0].value_counts()['True']

numbertrue = evaluation.iloc[:, 0][0].value_counts()['True']
```

I expected numbertrue to be a number that counted the number of True values, instead I keep getting an error "Too many indexers".

Comment: What function are you applying, and how do you apply it? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Its a custom function which takes a bunch of numeric values, and returns a True/false value followed by a bunch of numeric values, and instead of returning a dataframe row, it's returning a list in the dataframe row. The function is like 6 different files all put together and several pages long.

Comment: Please read the link. You don't need to show the exact code, just code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: evaluation = feedBatch.apply(lambda x: someproprietoryfunction(data, x), axis=1)